# Generate fake CSV to test with rspec

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

I want to test my method which import a CSV file.
But I don't know how to generate fake CSV files to test it.
I tried a lot of solution I already found on stack but it's not working in my case.

Here is the csv original file :

```
firstname,lastname,home_phone_number,mobile_phone_number,email,address
orsay,dup,0154862548,0658965848,orsay.dup@gmail.com,2 rue du pré paris
richard,planc,0145878596,0625147895,richard.planc@gmail.com,45 avenue du general leclerc
```

person.rb

```
 def self.import_data(file)
   filename = File.join Rails.root, file

   CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, col_sep: ',') do  |row|
     firstname, lastname, home_phone_number, mobile_phone_number, email, address = row

     person = Person.find_or_create_by(firstname: row["firstname"], lastname: row['lastname'], address: row['address'] )
     if person.is_former_email?(row['email']) != true
       person.update_attributes({firstname: row['firstname'], lastname: row['lastname'], home_phone_number: row['home_phone_number'], mobile_phone_number: row['mobile_phone_number'], address: row['address'], email: row['email']})
    end
  end
end
```

person_spec.rb :

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Person, :type => :model do


  describe "CSV file is valid" do
   file = #fake file
   it "should read in the csv" do
   end

   it "should have result" do
  end
 end

 describe "import valid data" do
  valid_data_file = #fake file
  it "save new people" do
   Person.delete_all
   expect { Person.import_data(valid_data_file)}.to change{ Person.count }.by(2)
   expect(Person.find_by(lastname: 'dup').email).to eq "orsay.dup@gmail.com"
 end

 it "update with new email" do
 end
end

describe "import invalid data" do
 invalid_data_file = #fake file
 it "should not update with former email" do
 end
 it "should not import twice from CSV" do
 end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used the [Faked CSV Gem](https://github.com/jiananlu/faked_csv) from https://github.com/jiananlu/faked_csv to achieve your purpose of generating a CSV File with fake data.

Follow these steps to use it:

1. Open your command line (i.e. on OSX open Spotlight with CMD+Space, and enter "Terminal")
2. Install Faked CSV Gem by running command `gem install faked_csv`. Note: If using a Ruby on Rails project add `gem 'faked_csv'` to your Gemfile, and then run `bundle install`
3. Validate Faked CSV Gem installed successfully by typing in Bash Terminal `faked_csv --version`
4. Create a Configuration File for the Faked CSV Gem and where you define how to generate fake data. For example, the below will generate a CSV file with 200 rows (or edit to as many as you wish) and contain comma separated columns for each field. If the value of field `type` is prefixed with `faker:` then refer to the "Usage" section of the [Faker Gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) https://github.com/stympy/faker for examples.

**my_faked_config.csv.json**

```
{
  "rows": 200,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "faker:name:first_name",
      "inject": ["luke", "dup", "planc"]
    },
    {
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "faker:name:last_name",
      "inject": ["schoen", "orsay", "richard"]
    },
    {
      "name": "home_phone_number",
      "type": "rand:int",
      "range": [1000000000, 9999999999]
    },
    {
      "name": "mobile_phone_number",
      "type": "rand:int",
      "range": [1000000000, 9999999999]
    },
    {
      "name": "email",
      "type": "faker:internet:email"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "faker:address:street_address",
      "rotate": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

5. Run the following command to use the configuration file my_faked_config.csv.json to generate a CSV file in the current folder named **my_faked_data.csv**, which contains the fake data `faked_csv -i my_faked_config.csv.json -o my_faked_data.csv`
6. Since the generated file may not include the associated Label for each column after generation, simply manually insert the following line at the top of **my_faked_data.csv** `firstname,lastname,home_phone_number,mobile_phone_number,email,address`
7. Review the final contents of the **my_faked_data.csv** CSV file containing the fake data, which should appear similar to the following:

**my_faked_data.csv**

```
firstname,lastname,home_phone_number,mobile_phone_number,email,address
Kyler,Eichmann,8120675609,7804878030,norene@bergnaum.io,56006 Fadel Mission
Hanna,Barton,9424088332,8720530995,anabel@moengoyette.name,874 Leannon Ways
Mortimer,Stokes,5645028548,9662617821,moses@kihnlegros.org,566 Wilderman Falls
Camden,Langworth,2622619338,1951547890,vincenza@gaylordkemmer.info,823 Esmeralda Pike
Nikolas,Hessel,5476149226,1051193757,jonathon@ziemannnitzsche.name,276 Reinger Parks
...
```

8. Modify your **person_spec.rb** Unit Test using the technique shown below, which passes in Mock data to test functionality of the `import_data` function of your **person.rb** file

**person_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Person, type: :model do

  describe 'Class' do
    subject { Person }

    it { should respond_to(:import_data) }

    let(:data) { "firstname,lastname,home_phone_number,mobile_phone_number,email,address\r1,Kyler,Eichmann,8120675609,7804878030,norene@bergnaum.io,56006 Fadel Mission" }

    describe "#import_data" do
      it "save new people" do
        File.stub(:open).with("filename", {:universal_newline=>false, :headers=>true}) {
          StringIO.new(data)
        }
        Product.import("filename")
        expect(Product.find_by(firstname: 'Kyler').mobile_phone_number).to eq 7804878030
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Note: I used it myself to generate a large CSV file with meaningful fake data for my [Ruby on Rails CSV app](https://github.com/ltfschoen/rails_csv_app). My app allows a user to upload a CSV file containing specific column names and persist it to a PostgreSQL database and it then displays the data in a Paginated table view with the ability to Search and Sort using AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Use openoffice or excel and save the file out as a .csv file in the save options. A spreadsheet progam.

Comment: Yes I already think about that but I thought there were more efficient way to do it.